# SqlConnection.Open throws error when trying to connect to Oracle server

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to Oracle database on my local machine. I have Visual Studio 2013 and Oracle Express 11g.

Here's my c# code:

```
    String str =
        "Data Source=localhost;" +
        "Initial Catalog=XE;" +
        "User Id=system;" +
        "Password=12345;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
        conn.Open();
```

However it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL

Does anybody know what's going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using an `Oracle` provider?

Comment: `SqlConnection` is the **SQL Server** specific provider - it doesn't work with Oracle ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the classes in the  `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace with Oracle.  `SqlClient` is only for Sql Server.  You need to use either an Oracle .Net provider or the classes in the  `System.Data.OleDb` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Check your *provider*, as I commented above....

Taken from [Oracle Web Site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/cook-dotnet-101788.html)...

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
             + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ORASRVR)(PORT=1521)))"
             + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));"
             + "User Id=***;Password=***;";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(); 
conn.ConnectionString = oradb;
conn.Open();
```

You may want to look at [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/) to help with which suits you best.